# Wrong "About Us" link in help drop down menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

When I click on the new 'About Us' link from the drop down menu at the top of the page, it gives me this page:

[image]

> ## Page Not Found
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

It affects all sites except Stack Overflow. Please fix the URL to match the one at the bottom of the page.

Comment: No repro, for me it links to http://stackoverflow.com/company/about which does exist. Besides, can't see any help drop down in the mobile theme, how did you come to see it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wasn't using mobile view - it did it just for that link, Also, looks like it's fixed now.

Comment: Super weird. For the record, I really dislike those new items, it's just noise in my opinion, cluttering the once-clean help drop down.

Comment: Appears to be fixed?

Comment: Yep, it's been fixed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We caught this shortly after we shipped too, so it's been fixed. You reported it *riiiight* in between.

Comment: There should be a [tag:status-you-were-too-fast] tag...